# How to continously update a tooltip message?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a frame with multiple elements, and that frame has a tooltip that can be updated very fast. It is really annoying that when you mouse over the frame, the tooltip message doesn't update, it stays the same until you move your cursor.

I have seen this similar question: [continuously updating tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427625/continuously-updating-tooltip)

But I need to do it to a QFrame which code was created with the designer.

I use the following code. I have tried to place the functions there but it doesn't work because the QFrame is generated inside `my_window.Ui_Form`, which is code auto generated by the designer.

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog, my_window.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        my_window.Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def event():#???
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can subclass `QFrame` and load it into the designer (https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example code from the similar question you posted. Add a grid in your designer, lets call it mygrid. Then add the custom widget (MyLabel) to it in your code with mygrid.addWidget().

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog, my_window.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        my_window.Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mygrid.addWidget(MyLabel())
```

This was my first post, hope it was usefull.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer! The problem is that my widget is not a label, but a frame which contains other widgets that are designed in the qtdesigner, if I use that code they would disappear right?

Comment: Is there alot of widgets in that QFrame? Otherwise jus subclass it in your code and use it there. Just make sure you have a frame for adding your stuff fo. Got anymore actual code to show.?